# Dimension reduction for multivariate functional target that varies in length

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, lstm, high-dimensional, functional-data-analysis

I have target features consisting of about 70 different discrete time-series and I want to use this data to learn a model. Now the data is of course very high-dimensional, as I can also use a very high resolution regarding the time-steps.

I came across multivariate functional Principal Component Analysis which I think suits my problem very well. The problem now is that the time-series vary in length from data point to data point. In other words: consider I have 2 data points with 70 time-series each. All the 70 time-series from data point 1 have the same length but a different length respective to the second data point.
Can one still apply multivariate functional PCA on this?

I also thought about using LSTMs (or recurrent neural networks in general) as auto-encoder and then using the encoder as dimension reduction but I am not able to produce 'much' data (somewhere in the ten thousand region) and I am not sure whether a LSTM is able to handle such high-dimensional data with less data points.

EDIT:
The data comes from observations and a corresponding simulation. One observation consists of 70 time series. The ultimate goal is it to do a simulation-based optimization, to be further specific to solve an inverse problem regarding the simulation. Thus I wanted to use a meta model/surrogate and hence I have to learn on the time series data.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve and how does dimension reduction help you to solve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Sycorax I want to solve a model calibration problem or in other words an inverse problem but it happens to be that that the computer model produces 70 time-series. The model is not dynamic and hence it actually produces 70 functional data. The state of art in this task is to use multivariate functional Principal Component Analysis but I have not seen a case where the functional data varies in length.

Comment: So your single observation contains 70 time-series? Is your intended mode of operation something like: 'I get 70 time-series, and I need to predict which source these came from'? What is the model for single time-series? Something like ARIMA, or more complex? Not sure PCA is the way to go here, but you could configure a model to predict such time-series, and encode its parameters into a vector. One thing to watch out for here is parametrisation, since even ARIMA models can fit the same data with different combinations of coefficients.

Comment: @Cryo Yes a single observation contains 70 time-series. Yes the intended mode of operation is to predict the source/parametrisation of my simulation. The model is a very complex simulation, thus the task is in the field of computer model calibration.

Comment: So it would seem you want to distill your time series to something that represents them. I am not sure PCA is the best thing here since time-series will carry the initial conditions. Is there a statistical model that you can leverage to describe the individual time-series? For example ARIMA/ARIMAX?

Comment: Please add this new information in comments to the post as an edit. On this site we prefer posts to be self-contained, and comments are often seen only by afew, and can be deleted!